# Angular2+ Using NgFor to create mat-tab with the same content

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ngFor to create some tabs according to a list with the mat-tab material.

However, I would like to only have a unique content. 
Indeed, the content is a graph and only the data changed. Therefore, when I click on one of the tabs, it calls the function **onTabChanged()** and the variable *data* is updated in the < nvd3 >.

This does not work properly. Because it creates three times nvd3.

In fact, I would like the tabs acting like a button. Because I tried some buttons but I prefer the design of the tabs.

```
<mat-tab-group class="col-10 offset-1" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab label={{tab.type}} *ngFor="let tab of datasetList; let index = index">
    <div>
      <nvd3 #nvd3 [options]="chart" [data]="data"></nvd3>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Inside the 3 tabs, you only want one content field ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly I want 3 tabs (or more) and only one div <nvd3> not three.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `mat-tab-nav-bar` instead of `mat-tab-group`.